# Compiling with Bigloo

Tags: scheme, compilation, racket, bigloo

I've written a scheme file in DrRacket/Scheme and I have my .rkt file. I need to now compile what I've written with Bigloo. I have Bigloo installed, but I'm not sure how to use it.

Anyone know how?

Answer (score 3):

To compile a Scheme module. invoke the `bigloo` compiler with the `-c` option:

```
bigloo -c foo1.scm
```

This will output an object file (.o). You can link object files into an executable with the command:

```
bigloo foo1.o foo2.o -o foo
```

You can also compile and link in a single step:

```
bigloo foo1.scm foo2.scm -o foo
```

See [this link](http://www-sop.inria.fr/mimosa/fp/Bigloo/doc/bigloo-31.html#The-compiler-environment-and-options) for more information.